# Get data from wp_posts of mysql in to variables of wordpress-php script

Tags: plugins, php, posts

I want to get post status, media information like the type of attachments added to the post etc in to my program. I tried this but doesn't work well

```
 $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  post_status FROM wp_posts WHERE 
   ID = 1  LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get_post` (see: [get_post reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)) to get a post like `$post = get_post(1);` and then say: `$post->post_status`

-- EDIT

Or even better use the `get_post_status` (see: [get_post_status](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_post_status)) like `$post_status = get_post_status(1);`